# Check for duplicate emailid

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, stored-procedures

I am checking for a dupliacte emaild using stored proc

```
     ALTER procedure [dbo].[Insertreg]

( @id int output,@FirstName varchar (50),@LastName varchar(50) ,@Dob datetime,
    @Gender varchar(20) ,@MobileNo nchar(10) ,@Country varchar(50) ,
    @State varchar (50),@EmailId varchar (50),@Password nchar (15),@result int output

)
as 
begin

if exists(select EmailId from Profile_Master where EmailId=@EmailId)
set @result=0
else
begin
set @result=1

insert into Profile_Master(FirstName,LastName,Dob,Gender,MobileNo,Country,State,EmailId,Password)
 values 
(@FirstName,@LastName,@Dob,@Gender,@MobileNo,@Country,@State,@EmailId,@Password)
set @id=SCOPE_IDENTITY()
return
end 
end
```

code behind

```
result = cmd1.Parameters.Add("@result", System.Data.SqlDbType.Int);
            result.Direction = System.Data.ParameterDirection.Output;
var id = cmd1.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

but when i debug if emailid exists i am getting id value as -1 how can i resolve this?

Comment: What rdbms, SQL-Server xxxx? Please tag it accordingly.

Comment: Show us also the sql of the SP (at least the relevant part of your output variable(s)).

Comment: Also, `id` is not an `Id` but just the number of affected rows since you're using `ExecuteNonQuery` instead of `ExecuteScalar` You should check `result` after `ExecuteNonQuery` to get the output variable.

Answer (score 0):

Calling [**ExecuteNonQuery()**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.executenonquery.aspx) will return the number of rows affected. As you did add an **outputParameter** you should access this one.

```
// access an output parameter
cmd1.ExecuteNonQuery();
var id = cmd1.Parameters["@result"].Value;

// OR: get the returnValue of a SP
var id = cmd1.ExecuteScalar();
```

**EDIT**

What about using this version of your sp

```
ALTER procedure [dbo].[Insertreg]
( @FirstName varchar (50),@LastName varchar(50) ,@Dob datetime,
    @Gender varchar(20) ,@MobileNo nchar(10) ,@Country varchar(50),
    @State varchar (50),@EmailId varchar (50),@Password nchar (15))
as 
begin

    if exists(select EmailId from Profile_Master where EmailId=@EmailId)
        select -1;
    else
    begin
        insert into Profile_Master(FirstName,LastName,Dob,Gender,MobileNo,Country,State,EmailId,Password)
        values (@FirstName,@LastName,@Dob,@Gender,@MobileNo,@Country,@State,@EmailId,@Password)
        select SCOPE_IDENTITY();
    end 
end
```

And afterwars only use

```
// no need for any output Parameters here...
int id = int.Parse(cmd1.ExecuteScalar().ToString())
```

to access your id value. Value will be greater than -1 if given mail is unique and -1 in case email already exists!

Comment: @result is a output parameter.

Comment: completly rewrote my answer, pls check it out and give some feedback

Answer (score 0):

Using `ExecuteNonQuery` with StoredProc returns -1. That's the expected behaviour.

Change your code to

```
if exists(select EmailId from Profile_Master where EmailId=@EmailId)
   select 0 as result
else
   select 1 as result
```

C#, you don't need to pass parameter here anymore

```
var id = cmd1.ExecuteScalar();
```

Since you are using OUTPUT parameter, you can also use @Pilgerstorfer Franz's approach

Comment: but i have to return the id  return id; if i use executescalar i am getting error.

Comment: I can see you have updated your question. I didn't see that part

Comment: why to use executescalar instead of executenonquery??

Comment: `ExecuteNonQuery` is OK but the returned value is the number of rows affected by INSERT, DELETE and UPDATE. For PROC, it is always -1. If you want to return value from PROC, use output param as pointed out. `ExecuteScalar` returns the first column of the first row

Answer (score 0):

`id` is not an `Id` but just the number of affected rows since you're using [`ExecuteNonQuery`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.executenonquery.aspx) instead of [`ExecuteScalar`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.executescalar.aspx) You should check `result` after `ExecuteNonQuery` to get the output variable.

```
result = cmd1.Parameters.Add("@result", System.Data.SqlDbType.Int);
result.Direction = System.Data.ParameterDirection.Output;
int numberOfAffectedRecords = (int)cmd1.ExecuteNonQuery();
// now result should have the output variable
```

If you want to have the newly created ID, you should use `ExecuteScalar`:

```
result = cmd1.Parameters.Add("@result", System.Data.SqlDbType.Int);
result.Direction = System.Data.ParameterDirection.Output;
int newID = (int)cmd1.ExecuteScalar();
// now result should have the output variable
```

Comment: In the first part are you checking the result after ExecuteNonQuery?? i am confused.

Comment: Yes, in both _parts_. You need to `ExecuteNonQuery` or `ExecuteScalar` first before you can inspect the `result` output-variable.

Answer (score 0):

This is the expected behaviour for [ExecuteNonQuery](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.executenonquery.aspx). 
Your query is not affecting any rows.

> For UPDATE, INSERT, and DELETE statements, the return value is the
>   number of rows affected by the command. When a trigger exists on a
>   table being inserted or updated, the return value includes the number
>   of rows affected by both the insert or update operation and the number
>   of rows affected by the trigger or triggers. For all other types of
>   statements, the return value is -1. If a rollback occurs, the return
>   value is also -1.

You get the result as follows:

```
result = cmd1.Parameters.Add("@result", System.Data.SqlDbType.Int);
result.Direction = System.Data.ParameterDirection.Output;
cmd1.ExecuteNonQuery();
var id = result.Value;
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try:

```
cmd1.ExecuteScalar();
var id=Convert.ToInt32(result.Value);
```